# Wordpress: Cannot find files and pages when uploaded in the server

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, server

I have recently uploaded a wordpress in my server. In the localhost, it is working but when I uploaded it, some pages cannot be found. I figured it was because of the paths.

All my template files are inside a theme folder. Some of the template files are calling some php files which can be found in the root directory. For example, the print button in the template-product.php calls the printProductProfile.php.

I am using the following jquery code but it's not working. It says page cannot be found. How can I fix this?

```
//jquery code in template-product.php
('#print').click(function(e){   
    var productID = document.getElementById('productID').value;
     popupWindow = window.open(
                '../printProductProfile.php?id='+productID, 
                'PDF Viewer',
                'height=700,width=800,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes');

});
```

Shown below is the structure of my folders and files.

```
public_html
  -printProductProfile.php
  -wp-content
     -themes
        -myTheme-child
            -template-product.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ABSPATH` Like

`ABSPATH.'/printProductProfile.php?id='+productID`

or use `'printProductProfile.php?id='+productID`

Comment: @user3383911 try using only 'printProductProfile.php' also, echo this `ABSPATH.'wp-content/themes/{your_theme}//printProductProfile.php` and paste the output here.